# Invite users to closed Facebook group that was created by a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

How can we programmatically invite people to our closed Facebook group that was created by our app?

We've recently switched from the 1.0 to the 2.2 API version with our Facebook app. In this new version of the Facebook graph api, the option to add users to a (closed) Facebook group (that was created by the app) is not possible anymore. Only admins, developers or testers of the app can be added using the API.

Because of this, we thought we just temporarily invite people by hand. This is possible with a manually created Facebook group, you are able to invite people using an invite field. However, when a Facebook group is created by an app, this invite field is nowhere to be found, so manually inviting people seems to be impossible.

So, no adding via the API and no manual adding... What remains?

We've seen the FB.ui Javascript dialog function that a user can use to request access to the group, but this isn't what we want, we want to invite people...

It almost seems like our closed group has become useless because we can't invite anyone anymore...

Is there a solution for our problem?

Thanks in advance,
Erik.

Comment: You are talking about App&Game Groups, I suppose? For those, the documentation says you should show the dialog to people to let them join. So you could send them a notification (if you have a canvas app) or maybe an email, that directs them to a page where you show them that dialog.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the App&Game groups. And yes, I could do that, but is this the only way? Can't I just send the invitation directly?

Comment: @ErikRave hi Erik did you find out how to programmatically add users to a group? I have many thousands of users I need to add - so I can't do it by hand!! any advice would be very helpful